# can't make JCarousel work

Tags: jquery, jcarousel, jcarousellite

I need to use "Jcarousel" plugin or "Jcarousel lite"
but they never work with me don't know why and what i do wrong!
here is my implementation,
http://uluva.com/carousel/
Thanks in advance.

JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        vertical: true,
        scroll: 2
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sliders">
    <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-ie7">
        <li><img src="thumb.jpg" alt="" width="70" height="70" ></li>
        <li><img src="thumb.jpg" alt="" width="70" height="70" ></li>
        <li><img src="thumb2.jpg" alt="" width="70" height="70" ></li>
        <li><img src="thumb2.jpg" alt="" width="70" height="70" ></li>
        <li><img src="thumb2.jpg" alt="" width="70" height="70" ></li>
        <li><img src="thumb2.jpg" alt="" width="70" height="70" ></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I solve it, the problem from the css file's reset elements 

    ...,li{
           display:inline;
    }

"li" selector should be block to work